# Issue Debugging Reason XML Won't Parse

Tags: android, xml

I am having some difficulties with my android app parsing an xml that contains links to PDF files.  It should open a listView showing all of the files listed in the xml.  However, most of the time it just freezes up on me.  The app was made by a developer no longer with us, and all I have is the apk and not the source files.  Is there a way to use the apk to get the source files and figure out what the issue is?  Android is not my forte and I'm at a loss with how to fix this.

UPDATE:

It appears that devices running 2.2 display all the songs just fine, while the newer versions of Android crash when ran.

Comment: The question title is a bit misleading to what the question is really about.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Sorry about that.  See update.  App is AdventuresInMinistry

Comment: It feels to me that your question is more about the possibility to get the source of a compiled APK than about parsing XML. There's not much to do with the XML problem unless you are able to change the source, is there?

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with android 2.2 on my HTC desire taking a *long* time to parse large XML files. There wasn't much I could do other than switch from DOM to SAX which for some reason was a lot quicker

However debugging this without source code is likely to be pretty difficult.  Not least because fixing the issue when and if you find it will require you to re-compile a new class in replacement for the one which keeps freezing.

**I would suggest you look into decompiling the APK back into source code.**

According to Wikipedia APK files are based on the Jar file format which in turn is a Zip file:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29

That makes this task a little easier as you won't need to look for a decompiler that is specific to android but a more generic Java Decompiler.

A quick search on google suggests this one:
http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

If you can decompile the app back to source code and then get that source code into eclipse and rebulild from source then you can start to debug.